# Trying to solve an equation using Lambert-W function

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, lambert-w

My equation is:

$$
\frac{w}{2\sqrt{\Pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(x-\delta)^2}{4 \sigma^2}}=x
$$

I am struggling to solve it fo $x$ knowing that: $ \sigma, w,\delta$>0.

Probably, it could be solved somehow using the Lamber-W function.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Lambert W function is of no use for this equation (except particular values of parameters, for example $\delta=0$). The most likely numerical calculus is required.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone, but there is a solution for $\delta = 0$. Firstly, let $\alpha = \frac{w}{2\sqrt{\Pi \sigma^2}}$. Then

$\alpha \exp(-\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2}) = x$

$\alpha = x \exp(\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2})$

$\alpha^2 = x^2 \exp(\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$

$\frac{\alpha^2}{2\sigma^2} = \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} \exp(\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$

$x^2 = 2 \sigma^2 W(\frac{\alpha^2}{2\sigma^2})$

$x = \sqrt{2 \sigma^2 W(\frac{\alpha^2}{2\sigma^2})}$

Note that negative answer to the square root is spurious, it appears because we squared the expression earlier.

Unfortunately, this trick does not work out of the box when $\delta>0$. Maybe there is another clever trick, maybe it is unsolvable, I don't know